# TraMineR: plotting with labels around 3000 distinct states

Tags: plot, legend, traminer

I am using TraMineR to represent around 40,000 sequences with around 3,000 distinct states. First I reduced the analysis for clustering, to 3,000 sequences (randomly selected). I have the sequence ready to be plotted.

I am having trouble to add the legend on the right side of any plot. If that is impossible given the size of the alphabet, at least can we add in a sequence top 10 most frequent sequence plot a legend subset of these 10 sequences. This is what I meant.

When I use seqfplot to plot the 10 most frequent sequences, is there a way to have a legend restricted to these 10 most frequent sequences for the readers to identify these sequences?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to suppress the legend by setting `with.legend = FALSE` in the `seqfplot` call and then make your own legend with the basic `legend` function.

Alternatively, you can re-create a state sequence object from the outcome of the `seqtab` function that returns the most frequent sequences and then plot this new object. The only difficulty, here, is to keep the original long labels and color palette. I illustrate using the `mvad` data that ships with `TraMineR`.

First we create the original state sequence object with long labels and weights.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.lab <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education",
              "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.shortlab <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], states = mvad.shortlab,
                   labels = mvad.lab, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)
```

Running

```
seqfplot(mvad.seq, idxs=1:5)
```

you can see than the five most frequent sequences include only 5 out the 6 states (JL does not occur among those sequences).

Now we build a state sequence object from the 5 most frequent sequences:

```
sf <- seqtab(mvad.seq, idxs = 1:5)
sff <- seqdef(sf, weights = attr(sf,"weights"))
```

To match the long labels and colors, we need to identify the position of the retained states in the original alphabet vector:

```
sti <- which(alphabet(sf) %in% alphabet(sff))
```

This allows us to rebuild `sff` with the wanted colors and long labels.

```
sff <- seqdef(sf, weights = attr(sf,"weights"), 
       cpal=cpal(sf)[sti], labels=mvad.lab[sti], xtstep=6)
seqfplot(sff)
```

[image]

Of course, the 100 % displayed percentage is not the percentage of all the sequences but of the five sequences in `sff`.

A solution to have the correct percentage would be to do

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
seqfplot(mvad.seq, idxs = 1:5, with.legend=FALSE)
seqlegend(sff)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help